# Using hibernate configuration with the Lift Framework

Tags: java, hibernate, scala, lift

I have started fooling around with Lift and I wanted to use it on a project that interacts with my legacy database.  I have already went through the trouble of getting a Hibernate configuration to work with this database.

So I was wondering if it is possible to build a Lift project that uses the Hibernate code that I have already written.  Can anyone show me any good examples or tutorials of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any ORM with lift, including Hibernate. There is a full example using JPA and hibernate [here](https://github.com/andreak/on-example-rpm)

If you have some more questions about that example, you may want to try the [Lift mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb) , where the developer who wrote can be reached.